# how to get the value from mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

a.remove({"name":'sonu'},function(e,o){});
a.insert({"name":userName,"title":userName,"age":'25'},function(e,o){});

});
 I now need to obtain these values

Comment: Some tips about editing your questions: format code snippets as code (use the {} icon in the editor); Give a little more context to help others understand your question; show what you have tried so far and why it does not work; specify your question a bit more clearly; see [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
a.findOne({name: userName}, function (e, o) {})
```